# Android ListView onItemclick plus custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I know this question has been asked for like 50 times. I have been reading the questions in here to try and find a solution to my issue. I have a ListView with a custom adapter which links to the row layout which consists of two TextView controls filling the entire the row. I am trying to catch all taps (or clicks) on the ListItem row. Though, this is totally unreliable. I get 7/10 success ratio. I want the ListView to catch all the tabs 100%. I have tried every solution here. Though, let me list them:

I have tried adding those lines on both the TextView elements

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Then, I added

```
android:clickable="false"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

I have added this line to the LinearLayout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

I even done the disabling programmatically. I have went to the row layout and done the click on the row. Same issue. I have spent 10 hours trying to find a proper solution that works 100% without luck. I tried tracing the issue too to make sure its nothing within my code. I noticed that on some of the long tabs (I did long tabs for testing only) the text would get the text selection marker even with those added:

```
android:clickable="false"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

I must have browsed over 30 pages on stackoverflow. I wonder if anyone can help me with my issue.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you listening for click events?

Comment: use recyclerview you'll have more power and control over clicks.

Comment: @Veneet Reddy, on onCreate, I have added the the listener after using setAdapter and even before it. I even attempted to make my MainActivity extend ListActivity.

Comment: @Salvatory Baya Is the transfer from ListView to RecycleView easy? Will it completely solve my clicking issue? Is there a simple example I can check for RecycleView? I am new to android programming.

Comment: @Salvatory Baya Thanks for the advice. I have followed it. It took me a while to understand the concept of RecylcerView + the mandatory ViewHolder imposed on it. I found the snippet for clicking and it worked really nice. I can get most clicks now without having to spam my screen.

Comment: @JohnAnderson. Glad it worked, i posted an answer with better explanation of why android came up with RecyclerView, you can mark it as an answer if everything went.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things that android can not denying was too buggy, is the handling of click in listView. With that fact, they decided to create an alternative which is the recyclerView. With recyclerView you'll have more power and control of pretty much anything including click. Plus RecyclerView will enhance performance.

Answer (score 0):

Salvatory Baya, suggested that I use a RecyclerView which I did. This solved the problem. Now, I am getting most of the clicks.